# Definition of vertices of a polytop in $\mathbb{R}_{+}^d$

Tags: geometry

Having the following set:
$V=\left\{v\in{}\mathbb{R_{+}^{d}}\hspace{2pt}:\hspace{2pt}\sum_{i=1}^dv_i=K\hspace{4pt}\text{and}\hspace{4pt}\forall{}v_i\hspace{2pt},v_i\leq{}1\right\}$. That is, all the vectors with entries between 0 and 1 that sum up to $K\leq{}d$.

I'm trying to show that $V$ is a polytop whose vertices are of the form $(1,1,...,1,0,...,0)$,$(0,1,0,0,1,...,0)$. i.e. all the vectors with $K$ ones and $N-K$ zeros.

I would like to show that this is *exactly* the group of vertices, that is, all the vertices are
of that form and all the vectors from that form are vertices of $V$.

I'm struggling with that because I'm trying to figure out the definition of a vectice and not sure how those satisfy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convex polytopes like the set $V$ you have, the definition of a vertex can be stated in an interesting linear-algebraic way:

A point $v \in V$ is a vertex if and only if, for all $x, y \in V$ and $t \in (0,1)$, if $tx + (1-t)y = v$ then $x = y = v$.

In general, this is the definition of an *extreme point* of a convex set $V$, and when $V$ is a convex polytope, the extreme points are called vertices.

Edit: also, the set of extreme points of a compact polytope in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the minimal set (by inclusion) whose convex hull is the polytope – this is a consequence of the Krein-Milman Theorem.

Comment: Hi, Thanks! So if i get it right, all the vectors of that form are extreme points because they fulfill the definition, also, extreme point of a polytope are called vertices, and finally that group of vertices is minimal bacause of that Krein-Milman Theorem. That's right? Why can I state that the minimal set whose convex hull is the polytope is that group?

Comment: That's right. We shouldn't use the word "group" here because there are no [groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_\(mathematics\)) in play (besides the additive group of $\mathbb{R}^n$). Anyway, to get minimality: suppose $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact and convex, and let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be such that $\operatorname{hull}(S) = P$. In particular, we have $S \subseteq P$. Now, every point in $P$ is a convex combination of points in $S$, but you can't produce an extreme point as a convex combination of non-extreme points! Thus, $S$ contains all of the extreme points of $P$.

Comment: You only need the compactness and Krein-Milman to get the other direction, i.e. that the convex hull of the set of extreme points is the original set! Also, why is this question tagged "group-theory"?

Comment: You are right, I mismatched "groups" with "sets". sorry. The only last thing I cannot see directly is why every point in $V$ is indeed a convex combination of the vertices I introduced. Does that need a proof or is there some simple explanation. Thanks again!

Comment: You should show this by induction on $d$. Hint: every element $\mathbf{x} \in V$ can be written as $t(0,0,\dots,0,1) + (1-t)\mathbf{y}$ for some $t \in [0,1]$ and some $\mathbf{y} = (y_1, \dots, y_d) \in V$ such that $y_d = 0$.